# Chrome extension: Copy text

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a simple chrome extension where I'd like to click an image and copy the href of the link next to it. I have everything in place, but the copy will not work for the life of me. I have the following premissions in my manifest:

"permissions": [
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite"
]

I then create an input with id "copyInp" and use the following function to copy to clipboard (tried to be as deliberate as possible here, so it's not the most compact):

```
function copyLinkToClipboard( link ) {
$("#copyInp").val(link);
var inp = document.getElementById("copyInp");
inp.focus();
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

};

After this runs, I get nothing new in my clipboard when I ctrl+v. Any ideas as to what's going wrong here? The input definitely has the text I want in it, and I have the permission in the manifest. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: is inp.val set? have you tried debugging? Chrome offers mighty debugging functionality. here a tutorial on how to debug background-scripts (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html). Nearly the same applies to content scripts.

Comment: inp.val is set. focus and select also worked properly. i verified by making the input visible and watching the text appear and get selected. the problem was entirely with chrome not allowing execCommand, which i was unable to do even from the console on a local page

Answer (score 7):

After a bit more digging I discovered I needed to use a background page. Apparently this is the only thing you can call document.execCommand on. So the fix is to create a background.html with the copy function and the input in it, add a listener like so:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(obj) {
        copyLinkToClipboard( obj.link );
});
```

and then use sendRequest to pass the text you want copied to the background page:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({link: linkText});
```

and don't forget to add the background page in the manifest

```
"background_page": "background.html",
```

voila. text copied to clipboard. would LOVE an easier way to do this (if security is the issue then why not make an api for extensions? or rather, why scrap the experimental api only to force us to do this stupid workaround?) but oh well, this will suffice for the time being

Comment: They had removed background-page, how can I get this to work? ;(

Comment: It's now moved to being "pages" under the "background" object.